# Replacing value in nested state with react functional components

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to use update state in a react function component but it is not working. I tried following a tutorial on pluralsite and apply it to my own project. Ideally this code should be finding the product based on the ID number and replacing the total with a new value.

Unfortunately I am getting an error saying that 'productData.find' is not a function and I'm not sure where the code being used for that is. Are there any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

This is what the data looks like. In this example I am saving the first element of the array.

```
export let data = [
    {
        name: "Name",
        description:
            "",
        products: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Name 1",
                material: 1.05,
                time: 25,
                total: 0,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Name 2",
                material: 3,
                time: 252,
                total: 0,
            },
        ],
    },
...
];
```

```
function CompareCard({}) {
    const index = 0;
    const [productData, setProductData] = useState(data[index]); 

function setTotalUpdate(id) {

        const productPrevious = productData.find(function (rec) {
            return rec.id === id;
        });

        const productUpdated = {
            ...productPrevious,
            total: 1,
        };
        const productNew = productData.map(function (rec) {
            return rec.id === id ? productUpdated : rec;
        });
        setProductData(productNew);
    }
setTotalUpdate(1)
}
```

Comment: on the actual version, your state have every time only one element on state, so maybe you don't need array on your state but directly object, can you explain what call your component, what the next step after this operation, the goal... to give you a better answer

Comment: And please create a const for index (const index = and not index)

Comment: Thank you!

This is a calculator which calculates each product's total based on the input for the 'material' cost. 

I have a container called ProductCalculator which will contain two compare cards. CompareCard.js will contain Product.js which handles each individual ProductData.product through a map function.  
The total cost of all products will be saved and displayed.

I'm not very well versed with state so any recommendation on how to handle this is helpful. I notice I'm really just updating an object. Is it state the only/best way to keep track of the changing values?

Comment: I'm getting an error now saying that 'Maximum update depth exceeded' by calling this function several times to update the total for each product. This might be too much for this question, but I'm not sure if anyone has any insight!

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
const [productData, setProductData] = useState(data[index])
```

you don't pass an Array on your state but an Object (the first element of your data so an Object) and Object don't have find method.

Try
const [productData, setProductData] = useState([data[index]])

with [] on our useState to put your Object on array

///////////////////////////////// Edit /////////////

Ok, I try your code, and I propose you this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Name",
    description: "",
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Name 1",
        material: 1.05,
        time: 25,
        total: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Name 2",
        material: 3,
        time: 252,
        total: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const CompareCard = () => {
  // setState with the subArray products from data[0], I use '...' (spread operator) inside a Array or an Object to make a shalow copy
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([...data[0].products]);

  const setTotalUpdate = (id) => {
    // find the product to change inside products collection, that's ok
    const productPrevious = productsData.find((rec) => {
      return rec.id === id;
    });

    // create a new product to change one property's value, you can do something like 'productPrevious.total = 1', same same
    const productUpdated = {
      ...productPrevious,
      total: 1,
    };

    // create a new products collection to update state
    const productNew = productsData.map((rec) => {
      return rec.id === id ? productUpdated : rec;
    });
    setProductsData([...productNew]);
  };

  const setTotalUpdateSecond = (id) => {
    // create a newState
    const newState = productsData.map((product) => {
      // condition if id === productId and do something
      if (id === product.id) {
        product.total = 1;
      }
      // both case, I return the product (change or not)
      return product;
    });

    setProductsData([...newState]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setTotalUpdate(1)}>Test old method on product 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTotalUpdateSecond(2)}>Test second method on product 2</button>
      {productsData.map((product) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>Product Id : {product.id} / Product Total : {product.total}</p>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default CompareCard;
```

Can you copy / past this, try and say me if it's what you want, if yes, I explain you where the confusion was. If not, explain me, what's the problem here and I modificate.

Comment: Second things, if you use index to put an only one object on your useState, why use a find because you now that your state is only one element so just compare your id with the element.

Comment: Thank you. This example only shows one object, but there are 4 with identical structures. I tried to imply that with the '...' but I think I'm sorry that was unclear. The real code has logic to determine the index value.
It turns out I needed to do productData.products.find because I'm searching for the id within the productData.products.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `productData` is not an array so `.find` would not work. You want iterate over the `products` property in your data, so do `productData.products.find(...)`

Comment: Thank you this was definitely the issue with `.find`. I didn't realize .find was array specific.